# An injective linear map admits a left inverse whose restriction to a given subspace is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> **Question.** Let $n<m$ be positive integers and $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $\mbox{rk}(A)=n$. Does there exist $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times(m-n)}$ such that $(I_n\;B)\cdot A$ is invertible? Equivalently, does $A$ have a left inverse $(C\;D)$ with $C\in\mbox{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$, $D\in\mathbb R^{n\times(m-n)}$?

**Motivation.** I needed/wanted an argument of this type when dealing with diffeomorphisms between manifolds in $\mathbb R^m$, where $A$ is the Jacobian of the composition of a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb R^m$ and an immersion of rank $n$, and $(I_n\;B)$ is a 'projection map'.

**Ideas.** $\det((I_n\;B)\cdot A)$ is a polynomial in the entries $(b_{11},\ldots)$ of $B$, so if it is zero for all $B$, it is singular over $\mathbb R[b_{11},\ldots]$. By expressing that all coefficients are $0$, I concluded the case $(m,n)=(3,2)$ but it's not obvious how to generalize this approach.

I'd be interested in a constructive proof as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $rank A= n$, it follows that $A^T A$ is invertible. Since $A^T$ is $n\times m$ matrix, write it as $A^T=(C \ \ D)$ where $C$ is $n\times n$ and $D$ is $n \times (m-n)$ matrices.

Now, consider $(C + It  \ \  D)$. Then define a polynomial $p(t)$ by
$$
p(t) = \det \left[ ( C + It \ \ D)\cdot A\right].
$$

Since $A^T A$ is invertible, $p(0) \neq 0$.

Choose $t$ such that $\det (C+ It) \neq 0$ and $p(t)\neq 0$. Then the matrix 
$$
(C+It)^{-1} (C+It \ \ D) = (I \ \ B)
$$
is the matrix you want.

Comment: But does $(C+It\ \ D)\cdot A=I$?

Comment: Oh, I will fit it to your first question, so that $(I \ \ B)\cdot A$ is invertible. I will edit in a few minutes.

Comment: It is edited now.

Comment: Wow, nice. So in fact we could have started from any left inverse instead of $A^T$.

Comment: Yes, any left inverse of $A$ will work indeed.

Comment: And this works over any field of cardinality $>2n$ :)